# How to differentiate between a keypress of more than one usb-keyboard connected to the same host (in C#)

Tags: c#, keyboard, usb

I need to differentiate between a keypress of (at least) two usb-keyboards connected to a single PC.
Is there a method/precedure available to decide if key 's' (for example) is pressed either by keyboard A or Keyboard B?
(preferable language is C#)

Pseudo-Code:

```
if (keyPressed == 's')
{ 
   if(keyboardID == 'A')
   {
       print("Key 's' was pressed by Keyboard A");
   }
   else if (keyboardID == 'B')
   {
       print("Key 's' was pressed by Keyboard B");
   }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend providing more context for your question. Is this going to run as a console application or a win forms application etc.

Comment: I'll be watching this for the answer, as I've been a bit curious myself (as well as with mice).  I'm sure it involves specifically identifying the address of the USB port being used, the IRQ, or similar.

Comment: windows or linux?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/177305/using-multiple-keyboards-with-different-keyboard-layouts-in-windows

Comment: There is no limit within the context, meaning it doesn't matter if the OS is Windows or Linux... I can choose the OS running on host-PC. Moreover, I can decide if it’s a console application or a win forms application.
When I think out of the box... it is also possible to install two VMs, attach each keyboard to a VM, and code a program which communicated from the VM via TCP-sockets to my host-PC...
But maybe there is a complete different easier way?

Comment: /dev/input/eventx -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060710/format-of-dev-input-event

Answer (score 1):

keystrokes are processed by the OS as *events*

**in linux** for every input device there is separate event queue in `/dev/input/event*` (`*` means the specific device number)

in linux you can list all input devices with the command `sudo lsinput` (input-utils)

you can capture the specific events for each of your keyboards, see [Linux keyboard event capturing /dev/inputX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775461/linux-keyboard-event-capturing-dev-inputx)

**in windows** this is similar. you can use `rawInput` and get a *handle* for each device. deeper information and example codes is in

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160627-00/?p=93755 ("*The device handle tells us which keyboard generated the input*... ")

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

[raw input handling (distinguishing secondary mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605538/raw-input-handling-distinguishing-secondary-mouse)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Short of getting to the driver level and intercepting the keystroke there, you really can't (I think).  I utilize a bluetooth keyboard and a bluetooth keypad and could not find a way to do what you are asking so the number 3 on the keypad would register different than the number 3 on the keyboard keypad.